# Importing a Milestone to Microsoft project is showing %complete as 99

Tags: ms-project, mpxj

I have a xml which, which has been created through net.sf.mpxj. in xml i have a milestone and a Task which are closed complete. when i import this xml to Microsoft project 2016, MileStone %Complete is changed back to 99%. 
For task i dont see any issue. its showing 100%

Few Observations:
Actual Finish is showing N/A( from XML i am sending actual end date, not sure why its becoming N/A)
% Work Complete is showing 0

Has anyone faced this issue before, if so could you please help me!.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a link to a sample file so I can take a closer look?

Comment: Thanks Jon, here is the link for xml
https://pastebin.com/eLCpgvxi


below is the link for source code which was used to generate xml
https://pastebin.com/DgjTRzFr

Comment: @JonIles, sorry to bother you, requesting you to take a look when you got some time. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a quick look at this using your sample XML file. I tried various combinations of date, work, and duration attributes to get Project to report the percent complete correctly, but the only thing which worked for me was to supply an explicit percent complete value for the task. The only thing I can think is that Project is trying to calculate the percent complete value, but has a rounding error which means you never quite get to 100%.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time Jon , Please see this file https://pastebin.com/3jBUN33C. its still reproducible even after setting Percent Complete for the task.  Thank you again for taking your time on this

Comment: really appreciate your time looking in to this and helping me, requesting you to take a look when you got some time. Thanks – Akhilesh

Comment: lles, Thanks for your time on this, can you please help me on the questions above.

Comment: lles, Thanks for your time on this, can you please help me on the questions?